# Hibernate search problem - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate

I have the following exception when adding a new record using hibernate. I am also using Hibernate search to create index.

This is my exception.

```
Jun 11, 2009 1:01:23 PM org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException <init>
SEVERE: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.unproxy(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.addWorkToBuilderQueue(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.processWorkByLayer(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.notifyLocalSynchsBeforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCTransaction.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:140)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.dao.PurchaseDetailsDAO.savePurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetailsDAO.java:422)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.presentation.PurchaseItemsAction.execute(PurchaseItemsAction.java:56)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 11, 2009 1:01:23 PM org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction notifyLocalSynchsBeforeTransactionCompletion
SEVERE: exception calling user Synchronization
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.unproxy(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.addWorkToBuilderQueue(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.processWorkByLayer(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.notifyLocalSynchsBeforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCTransaction.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:140)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.dao.PurchaseDetailsDAO.savePurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetailsDAO.java:422)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.presentation.PurchaseItemsAction.execute(PurchaseItemsAction.java:56)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 11, 2009 1:01:23 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure <init>
SEVERE: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate)
org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Access a Sealed WorkQueue which has not been sealed
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.WorkQueue.getSealedQueue(WorkQueue.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.performWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.afterCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.notifyLocalSynchsAfterTransactionCompletion(JDBCTransaction.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:152)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.dao.PurchaseDetailsDAO.savePurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetailsDAO.java:422)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.presentation.PurchaseItemsAction.execute(PurchaseItemsAction.java:56)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 11, 2009 1:01:23 PM org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction notifyLocalSynchsAfterTransactionCompletion
SEVERE: exception calling user Synchronization
org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Access a Sealed WorkQueue which has not been sealed
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.WorkQueue.getSealedQueue(WorkQueue.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.performWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.afterCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.notifyLocalSynchsAfterTransactionCompletion(JDBCTransaction.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:152)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.dao.PurchaseDetailsDAO.savePurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetailsDAO.java:422)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.presentation.PurchaseItemsAction.execute(PurchaseItemsAction.java:56)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
- INFO Save PurchaseDetailsVO Ends.
- INFO Getting all PurchaseDetails List Using Hibernate Search Starts...
```

Answer (score 9):

This error means that you're trying to access a lazily-loaded property or collection, but the hibernate session is closed.  Lazy loading in Hibernate means that the object will not be populated (via a database query) until the property/collection is accessed in code.  Hibernate accomplishes this by creating a dynamic proxy object that will hit the database only when you first use the object.  In order for this to work, your object must be attached to an open Hibernate session throughout it's lifecycle.  Check to see how you're managing your session.  You may need to reattach objects to a new session if the session is being closed in some other place.

Comment: you could link your sources when you cite them (unless the opposite happened?) http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/hibernate/cause-and-solution-of-org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-error/

Comment: My answer is the original, I wrote it on June 11th, 2009.  The link you posted is a blog from 2011, so he must have copied it and pasted it in his blog, which is fine.  If I had copied it off of his blog, I would have posted a link to the full explanation.

Comment: My bad. I did not spot the posting date of the article!

Answer (score 5):

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html sais:

attach

**Purpose**

Attaches a detached domain instance to the Hibernate session bound to the current thread

**Examples**

def b = Book.get(1)
b.title = "Blah"
b.save(flush:true)
b.discard()

…
if(!b.isAttached()) {
    b.attach()
}

**Description**

Grails uses Hibernate which manages each persistent object in a persistence session. A new session is created per request and is closed at the end of the request. If an object is read from the session and placed into a web scope such as the HttpSession it is seen as detached, since the persistence session has been closed. You can use the attach() method to re-attach an existing persistent instance to the persistence session of the current request.

Answer (score 1):

Unless told to do otherwise, Hibernate 3.0+ will lazily load collections....

Also, unless told to do otherwise, hibernate will manage it's own sessions during the execution of, in your case, a web app request... it closes and opens new sessions as it sees fit. So the session that retrieves a parent may not be the same as the one asked to retrieve children.

You can apply an OpenSessionInView pattern to the request to keep a single session (reused) throughout the request. There are number of ways apply the pattern: as a Filter (Spring's OpenSessionInViewFilter), as an interceptor (Spring's OpenSessionInViewInterceptor), apparently as a webflow listener (Spring's HibernateFlowExecutionListener), or apply it yourself right at the point in the code that starts the whole mess.

Other approaches: 
turn off lazy loading (!), 
actively load an object graph: Hibernate.initialize(collection)