# Hibernate merge() with versioning

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate 3.6, mappings in XML.

Starting off with the following schema.

```
public class Card {
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private CardType cardType;

  private User user;//many-to-one
  ...
}

public class User {
  ...
  private int version;//Need to be strict about version on this table
  private Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<Card>();//cascade="all-delete-orphan"
  ...
}
```

If I do the following :
  
1: Load an existing user
  
2: Close session , work in detached state client side. Add transient tags.
  
3: Return the user to server, openSession(), beginTransaction(), saveOrUpdate(user), commit().

I get the following error 
"Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)"
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

So far this makes sense to me. CardType & Card need to have their indexes updated. So I expect to change my step 3 to merge() before saveOrUpdate().

If I do this it copies all properties from detached , including version, into the session aware object. This of course means my optimistic locking strategy fails - not warned of version problems.

What is the strategy supposed to be in this situation?

--Post updated to show some session handling code--

```
public synchronized static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  if (sessionFactory == null) {
    final AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration = configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.setInterceptor(interceptor);
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    AbstractSessionAwareConstraintValidator.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  }
  return sessionFactory;
}
```

Test code something like this

```
sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
//Find user here
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
//Edit User, add tags out of session. (not using OSIV)
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
user = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge();//Only works if I do this
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
```

As far as Im aware there is nothing "non standard" in my hibernate.cfg.xml, but just listing these 3 lines in case
    1
    thread
    org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider

I hope thats enough code to demonstrate session usage. Having posted this, Im wondering if its possible that the interceptor could affect session management?

Comment: Why would it fail? You want your version property to be copied. This is precisely what guarantees that the flush will throw an exception if the version has been modified by another user.

Comment: I don't feel LazyInitializationException normal... I suspect there is some problem in the transaction setting

Comment: JB Nizet, you are right of course. I dont know what I was thinking there. So then the question remains, is the correct practice to merge or is there some other reason Im getting LazyInitException as Adrian suggests? Should Hibernate Search be doing what it needs in that new session before it completes?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Hibernate Search, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle the Session? During indexing the Session must still be open so that the indexer can load lazy loaded associations. In webapps often the Open Session In View pattern is used to have an open Session during the whole request. You would need to post some more specific code to get more concrete feedback. The alternative is to eager load the associations (probably not a good idea).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979809/hibernate-search-problem-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session